# Spring boot WS: Is posible remove all attachments from a instance of MessageContext class?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have developed a WS with Spring boot. In the interceptor I want to modify the request and delete all attachments. I have tried the following:

```
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    WebServiceMessage requestReceived = messageContext.getRequest();
    if (requestReceived instanceof SaajSoapMessage) {
        SaajSoapMessage message = ((SaajSoapMessage) requestReceived);
        message.getAttachments().remove();
    }
    return true;
}
```

but remove() is not supported in that iterator.

Is it possible to delete all attachments?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but the way you are trying to remove the attachments does not seem to be right. Ideally you get an iterator and use it to iterate over the elements and deleting the ones you desire (in your case 'all' elements). Something like below:

```
if (requestReceived instanceof SaajSoapMessage) {
    SaajSoapMessage message = ((SaajSoapMessage) requestReceived);
    Iterator<Attachment> itr = message.getAttachments();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        itr.next();
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vini, it works perfectly, the exception is not generated but it does not remove them from the Message. Does the message have to be transformed? When the flow continues, at the next stage of processing the request, the attachments remain.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well, when I delete the attachments, these headers that I want to delete are kept in the message: . `------=_Part_0_989464880.1672306805146
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>`